# Macro in class definition

Tags: c++

class is defined using Macro. Not sure what is the significance of MACRO DEBUG_API  here.  [I understand #define is used to 
turn on or off some specific set of code.] But below code I cannot grasp. any explanation would be appreciated

```
#define DEBUG_API

class DEBUG_API Cdebug
{
     public:
     /*
        constructor, methods here.
     */
};
```

Comment: Without more context, this isn't possible to answer in a satisfactory way.

Comment: `DEBUG_API` is simply replaced with nothing. It is a nice example of macros obfuscating code

Comment: Based on my knowledge of C++, I'm not aware of any syntax that could possibly be valid between the `class` keyword and the class name in a class definition. Would be interested if anyone else can speak to that...

Comment: Usually macros in context similar to this can be switched to change the behavior of the code, but I can't think of a use in this case. I think it may just be used as a marker that `Cdebug` is part of the `DEBUG_API` and nothing more

Comment: @bgoldst `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: @bgoldst, `DEBUG_API` can be replaced with something like `test {}; class`, for example :P

Comment: This is often for use by some other tool that analyzes the source. For instance, Qt uses it for its "signal" and "slot" markers, and Cocoa for interaction with Interface Builder. What it's for in this particular case is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining this macro, you can choose [attributes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) that will be applied to the class. These can be standard or compiler-specific attributes.

Your particular example is most probably an instance of the usual pattern for DLL headers under MSVC. Depending on a compile-time switch, `DEBUG_API` will be set to either :

- `__declspec(dllexport)`, which will make MSVC generate a .lib file containing the class' thunk; this is used when compiling the library as a DLL;
- `__declspec(dllimport)`, which will make MSVC link against the thunk generated above; this is used when linking with the DLL;
- Nothing, which won't alter the behaviour of the class. This is used to link statically against the library.