# Macro before class name

Tags: c++

I was recently looking over some code and I've stumble upon this:

```
class IDATA_EXPORT IData {
    /* .... */
}
```

Where `IDATA_EXPORT` is not more than :

```
#ifndef IDATA_EXPORT
    #define IDATA_EXPORT
#endif
```

What is `IDATA_EXPORT` in this case? (I mean, is it type like int, char etc ... ?)

Comment: It's a macro that expands to nothing. So it's like it never existed.

Comment: And what role does it have in the definition of the class?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37487907/3233393), but that one is at -2.

Comment: More or less [common practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/81h27t8c.aspx) at least for Windows. Define the macro to something else and you have changed the attributes of all classes that use the macro in their declaration. Note that for C++11 and up this is also the place where [class attributes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) go, so we might see this more often in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most likely at some point in time, or under some conditions it was defined as (for example, under MSVC):

```
#define IDATA_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

Which was used to indicate the classes to publicly export from the library.

Using the macro, the developer could alternate between exporting classes and not exporting anything, without having to go over each individual class.

This is often part of a macro pattern which alternates between importing and exporting classes, depending on whether the code is compiled from the library, or from a program dependent on the library. It would then look something like:

```
#ifdef IS_LIBRARY // <--this would only be defined when compiling the library!
   #define IDATA_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
#else
   #define IDATA_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)  
#endif
```

For more information, see [dllexport, dllimport on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3y1sfaz2)

Comment: I'll be looking into what you've said, because there are still many things I do not know. This will be a good starting point. Thanks