# C++ Class definition in Cgicc.h

Tags: c++, class, templates

I was reading [Cgicc library](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/doc/Cgicc_8h-source.html).

The line number 00103 says class definition of cgicc class.
class CGICC_API Cgicc {

I can understand '**class**' keyword is used for to say it is a class. And '**Cgicc**' is a Class Name. But What is that '**CGICC_API**'.
When I study c++ course, I became to know that the Syntax of class definition is

```
class Class_Name
```

But It has three arguments. What is that '**CGICC_API**' in that code? What it is referring for?
As well as please explain these following lines too.

```
00054 #ifdef WIN32
00055   template class CGICC_API std::vector<FormEntry>;
00056   template class CGICC_API std::vector<FormFile>;
00057 #endif
```

Comment: [Near-duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37487907/3233393) (that one is about class definitions, not explicit template instantiations).

Answer (score 1):

This is a preprocessor definition that is used to mark classes as imported OR exported from a DLL library. Here is an actual macro definition from a library source code:

```
#ifdef WIN32

// export library symbols
#ifdef CGICC_EXPORTS
#    define CGICC_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define CGICC_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define CGICC_API
#endif /* WIN32 */
```

First thing to note, is that it is a Windows-only definition, on other platforms it's just an empty preprocessor identifier.

And another one, is that a macro definition is controlled by the CGICC_EXPORT option, so when you build this library you add CGICC_EXPORT definition to compiler flags and all symbols marked with CGICC_API are now __declspec(**dllexport**). From the other side, when you include public library headers there is no CGICC_EXPORT option and all symbols marked with CGICC_API are now __declspec(**dllimport**).

So basically, this trick makes possible to use same headers when building a Windows DLL (an exporting process) and then as public library headers (an importing process).