# Extra underscored name in a c++ function

Tags: c++, function

I understand what c++ functions need: type name (parameters) {statements}. What is it called when a function has an extra name like this:

```
_API8810AFUNC int API8810A_GetAPI8810AUSBDeviceCnt(int *pnUSBDeviceCnt);?
```

_API8810AFUNC is defined as:

```
#ifdef _BUILD_API8810ADLL
#define _API8810AFUNC  __declspec(dllexport )
#else
```

Does the "_API8810AFUNC" mean the function needs to be called differently? And does this have a name in c++?

Comment: Check your code base for `#define _API8810AFUNC`.  It should be defined as something(possible nothing, whitspace).

Comment: Some implementations or external tools like to define empty `#define` names to "tag" certain variables or functions. Other times, they use defines as alias for compiler intrinsics.

Comment: Seriously. Google. Please.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487907/macro-in-class-definition/37488286) (that one is about `dllexport`ed classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

In this case, it's a macro — and one with an illegal name, to boot* — that expands to `__declspec(dllexport)`. We can easily Google this to find that [it's a Microsoft *attribute* for use with DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

It could also have expanded [conditionally] to nothing, or it could have expanded to a different attribute, or it could expand to a storage class specifier (like `static` or `extern`).

To directly answer your question, the actual syntax of a function definition, per C++14, is as follows:

*function-definition*:
   *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> declarator virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> function-body*
*function-body*:
   *ctor-initializer<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement*
   *function-try-block*
   `= default ;`
   `= delete ;`

So it's a little more complicated than *"type name (parameters) {statements}"*, but you're not far off.

---

<sub>* `[C++14: 17.6.4.3.2]:` *[..]* Each name that *[..]* begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use. *[..]*</sub>